# Google Cloud functions not available as a serverless network endpoint except via Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm trying to configure a Google Cloud Function as a backend for a load balancer.

For that, I'm creating a Serverless network endpoint group, in the same region as the functions.

If I choose the type as Cloud Run, then I can see my functions (which are HTTP-triggered):

[image: I am able to pick a function via Cloud Run]

But if I choose the type as Cloud Function, then I can't see my functions, only a message saying "No Cloud Function exists in currently selected region and currently selected project".

[image: The same function isn't visible as a Cloud Function]

What are the requirements for a function to be accessible in this context? I've tried deploying *--ingress-settings=internal-and-gclb --allow-unauthenticated* but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you deploying a Global HTTP Load Balancer? Or another type of HTTP load balancer (regional, internal,...)? In addition did you deployed a Cloud Functions gen2?

Comment: It's a Global HTTP Load Balancer. All my functions are gen2.

Comment: Because Gen2 runs on Cloud Run behind the scene, your function appear as a Cloud Run service in your NEG and not as a Cloud Functions. It's a flaw of that design. might be fixed in the futur, but for now, you have to use it as a Cloud Run service and not as a Cloud Functions!

Answer (score 2):

Posting Sir @GuillaumeBlaquiere comment as answer just in case other users have the same concern they can use this post as a guidance.

I agree with sir @GuillaumeBlaquiere as I replicate this concern, to use Cloud Function in your Serverless network endpoint group type you need to choose Cloud Run. Once you choose Cloud Run, the name of your Cloud Function will appear under Select Service.

[image]